# Node.js: encoding unkown with fs.createWriteStream

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, fs

I am trying to set the encoding for a stream to `utf-16le` like this `fs.createWriteStream(file_name, {flags:'a', encoding: 'utf-16le'});`

However, when the file is created and I check the file encoding it says `binary`

below is the output of `file -I file_name` which tell me the encoding in which the file got created

`application/octet-stream; charset=binary`

Here above i see `charset=binary`, but i had specified `utf-16le`

How can i ensure that file created by stream is under the specified encoding.

Thanks.

Comment: what means *I see that the encoding reads `binary`*? do you create a read stream?

Comment: @appleapple, i hae updated my question, apologies for not being clear

Comment: What exactly does `file -I key` mean?

Comment: key is my filename, it prints out the encoding, i will update my question with more detail

Comment: What operating system are you using? The Linux `file` utility does not have a `-I` option, for example.

Comment: @Pointy i am using Mac OS

Comment: can you read the file correctly? maybe it's just `file -I` failed to identify `utf-16le`

Comment: It would probably help if you would write a *separate* Node program to open the file with your desired encoding and see if you can *read* the written content correctly. The operating system may not natively keep track of the encoding scheme for a file; Linux certainly doesn't.

Comment: @appleapple, i am comparing my file with source file and on source file if i execute `file -I` it correctly identifies the encoding to `utf-16le`

Comment: @opensource-developer did you copy the whole stream of source file? otherwise maybe there is not enough information about encoding (I don't use Mac OS, so I just guess)

Comment: @appleapple, i write to my stream like `writeStream.write(body, {encoding: 'utf-16le'})` and while reading decode from source like `const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-16le');`